# Avatar Not Showing Laravel

Tags: laravel, image, src, avatar

I'm working with laravel framework, I have to create a profile so I changed the table User created in the Auth.. all works perfectly. I also added a Picture for the Profile picture or Avatar in the User table.

I made a profile page Image are showing and even to my nav bar.

this is the code I used.. and it work in other pages.

```
 <img src="img/avatar/{{Auth::user()->picture}}">
```

this one is for my logo image I put the {{URL::asset}} because it's not showing also in another pages

```
 <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/weblogo.png') }}">
```

then it works perfectly in all pages

but when I try to use it in the image from my database, It won't work and said

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('img/avatar/{{Auth::user()->picture}}') }}">
```

syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ')'

in my view

but when I try this, it won't work with all the pages

```
 <img src="img/avatar/{{Auth::user()->picture}}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `asset` as below

```
<img src="{{ asset('img/avatar/'.Auth::user()->picture) }}">
```

Or if you want to use `URL::asset` then

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('img/avatar/'.Auth::user()->picture) }}">
```

Comment: I'm so dumb.. thank you so much.. it works!.. Thank you man. God bless :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `{{` again inside `{{ }}`

**Change**

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('img/avatar/{{Auth::user()->picture}}') }}">
```

**to**

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('img/avatar/'.Auth::user()->picture) }}">
```